# I am getting a "no main manifest attribute, in name-server-1.0.0.jar" despite the fact that I have a main manifest attribute

Tags: java

I am building my jar with the following command after making some edits:

```
jar cf name-server-1.0.0.jar *
```

In my META-INF (which is included in the * above), I have the file MANIFEST.MF, which contains the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: jenkins
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_171
Main-Class: class.Location.GoesHere
```

I don't want to put my actual Main-Class, as it may give away some information about the application.

Now obviously as I am building with jar cf, the manifest.mf is not correct, but it should still pull these values and deliver them to the JAR file, correct? Or do I need to do some other build procedure here.

I am just trying to make a quick hotfix here.

Is there some other argument or data I need to pass in here?

Comment: Use the m flag to provide a manifest to jar.

Comment: Or use M (alone) to allow META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in the normal file-args to be used and not overridden by jar's default-generated manifest, or use e (with classname) to include a main-class entry in the default-generated manifest. Practically a smorgasbord of choices.